# How to solve "Dependencies Missing" error occurred while creating Conda environment using 4.0.0 and python 2.7.x

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

> conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0 
>   Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org 
>   Fetching package metadata: .... 
>   Solving package specifications: . 
>   Error:  Dependencies missing in current win-64 channels:
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py35_0 -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py35_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py34_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py27_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py35_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py34_0 -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py27_0 -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py27_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py34_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
>   - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

anaconda search -t conda blas * mkl